# List top 5 authors with most posts

Tags: customization, users, page-template

How are you?

I have a blog which have 20 authors. I want to write code to show the 5 author who have more posts.

like this:

Adam (10 Posts)
Khal (8 Posts)
Yous (5 Posts)
Moha (3 Posts)
Yousef (1 Post)

but I don't know how can do it that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using WordPress 3.1+? There's a nice `get_users()` function that'll do the trick! However, you will need a little magic to boot:

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse_11832_pre_user_query' );

/**
 * Adds "post_count" to the SELECT clause. Without this, the "post_count"
 * property for users will be undefined.
 * 
 * @param object $wp_user_query
 */
function wpse_11832_pre_user_query( $wp_user_query ) {
    if ( $wp_user_query->query_vars['orderby'] == 'post_count' )
        $wp_user_query->query_fields .= ', post_count';
}
```

And example usage:

```
<?php foreach ( get_users( 'order=DESC&orderby=post_count&number=5' ) as $user ) : ?>

    <?php echo $user->display_name; ?> (<?php echo $user->post_count; ?> Posts)

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Important**: You *must* order by `post_count`, otherwise it will be undefined.

Comment: thank you , but the code didn't work. Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_users() in /home/abosami/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-php-widget/wp-php-widget.php(52) : eval()'d code on line 1.

Comment: Note: I include it in PHP widget

Comment: As he said, make sure you're running 3.1, otherwise this function won't work.

Comment: Upgrade to 3.1!

Comment: This is not working in wordpress 3.4.2. `<?php echo $user->post_count; ?>` is blank even if users have posts. I'm unable to debug it.

Comment: @Blue I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Work, i try ussing...

```
<?php foreach ( get_users( 'order=DESC&orderby=post_count&number=5' ) as $user ) : ?>

<?php 
    if ($user->post_count > 0) {
        echo $user->display_name.' ( '. $user->post_count .' Posts)<br/>';
    }
?>
```